# Netty application optimization

Tags: performance, sockets, netty

I'm writing a local HTTP server based on Netty. When I make a stress test, I'm limited on 400 requests/second.

To optimize my server, I've written a simple server based on Netty, that just sends "Hello World" to the client, and I launched a stress test with Gatling 2, and with this server, I've got the same result (limited to 400 req/s).

I use Yourkit for profiling, there is no extra GC activity, and my open/closed sockets are limited to 480 sockets/s.

I work with a MacBook Pro, with 4 cores, 16 GB of RAM, and I use Netty 4.1.

I'm surprised to be limited at 400 req/s, because the result of other benchmark tests show >20 000 req/s, or more. I understand that there are hardware limits, but 400 req/s, for a sending "hello World" on a 4 cores + 16 GB of Ram is very low.

Thank you in advance for your help, I don't know where to begin to optimize my Netty code.

Are there any concrete guidelines of optimizing Netty?

Here the source code of my hello world server, followed by the handler of my connections:

```
public class TestServer {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("TestServer");

    int nbSockets = 0 ;

    EventLoopGroup pool = new NioEventLoopGroup() ;

    private void init(int port) {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(100) ;


        try {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap().group(bossGroup);

            b.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder(8192, 8192 * 2,
                                    8192 * 2));
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());

                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new TestServerHandler(TestServer.this));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
                            System.err.println("Error");
                            super.exceptionCaught(ctx,cause);
                        }


                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100000)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,false)
                    .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY,false)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR,true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,10000)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);;

            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()  {
                    System.err.println(nbSockets);
                    nbSockets = 0 ;
                }
            },1, 1,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;


            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            System.err.println("Coucou");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestServer testServer = new TestServer() ;
        testServer.init(8888);
    }
}
```

and here is the source code of my handler:

```
public class TestServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private final TestServer testServer;

    public TestServerHandler(TestServer testServer) {
        this.testServer = testServer ;
    }


    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            process(ctx, msg);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void process(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buildHttpResponse()).addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(Future<? super Void> future) throws Exception {
                ctx.channel().close() ;
                testServer.nbSockets ++ ;
            }
        }) ;
    }

    public DefaultFullHttpResponse buildHttpResponse() {

        String body = "hello world" ;
        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        ByteBuf byteContent = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(bytes);
        HttpResponseStatus httpResponseStatus =HttpResponseStatus.OK;

        DefaultFullHttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                httpResponseStatus, byteContent);


        return httpResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: I ran apache bench locally on your code: `ab -n 100000 -c 100 http://localhost:8888/`. It reported over 16 000 req/s

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I'll check why i don't have the same result with gatling.

Comment: @forty-two How did you manage to get such a high number? Running this same ab on my laptop (OSX) makes connections refused after ~16.500 connections. What does your machine look like? How did you set up your TCP stack?

Comment: @StephaneLandelle A Dell 6530 with I7 and 16Gb, Vanilla ubuntu 14.04. I didn't tweak the TCP stack at all.

Comment: @forty-two Thanks. Better hardware than mine + OSX update had reset my TCP tuning to defaults, which are super poor on OSX on contrary to Linux. Still, I suspect you could run into the same ephemeral port starvation issue if you were to run your ab test with more iterations. On my laptop, I reach 8.000rps with both ab and Gatling until ephemeral port starvation kicks in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've disabled keep-alive and are closing the connection on every request, so I suspect you spend most of your time opening and closing HTTP connections.

> because the result of other benchmark tests show >20 000 req/s, or more

Which other benchmarks are you referring to? There's a very good chance they were both pooling connections, and using HTTP pipelining, hence a very different usage from yours.

Back to your original question (how to optimize Netty), there's two kind of things you could do:

- Micro-optimize allocations: using pooled ByteBuffers, or even better computing them only once
- Switch to [native epoll transport](http://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html) (Linux only)

But all those improvement won't probably amount to much compare to connection handling.

Comment: Thank you Stephane for your answer. I changed the keep-alive parameter and put it true, but it doesn't change the result of my test. Is keep-alive change something in real life application when i get connections from differents clients ? my guess is that keep-alive is applicable when i've connections from the same client ? Anyway, is 400 req/s a limit that a java server can handle ? I changed the java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider param to put it to "sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorProvider" (Mac), and i get no change.

Comment: Last remark, when i switch back to Old io (blocking io), i've the same result. Something is wrong in my code.

Comment: You're manually closing the connections: ctx.channel().close() ;

Comment: Only you can know how your clients behave. Usually, you set up a keep-alive timeout on server, such as 5s, so that clients can reuse connections for fetching resources.

Comment: And to make things clear: the limit you're hitting is not 400 req/s but 400 connections/s. And the limit is mostly your OS. So it doesn't matter if you're using OIO or NIO. Turning back TCP_NODELAY to true might help.

Comment: @bsh Note that your Netty code is broken: you should reply and close once you've received a LastHttpContent, not as soon as you have the Request.

Comment: Thank you Stephane, i forget a HttpObjectAggregator added in my original application. You're right, why i'm blocked at 16k connections on OSX ?

Comment: Default ephemeral port range of course! My original set up was reset when I upgraded to El Capitan...

Comment: But still, increasing the ephemeral port range will only push the issue forward, not remove it, because of the TIME_WAIT state. Hence my question to @forty-two regarding his server and set up. I suspect if he set his maximum segment lifetime to a very low value.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephane, it's a little bit clear for me now.